# How to post images to users' wall (or in folders/albums) on Facebook (2013)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook's PHP SDK. I looked [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) ([official documentation by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/)) for help. It is not working for me because I am using images hosted externally but if I try to upload files hosted within my server then it works fine.

Is there any new way to do this. Please try to explain both (Posting to feed and to some folder/album). Sorry for this question but others here were of no help to me.

Please suggest any PHP editor that is compatible with Facebook's API. (Auto-completion etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Stack is normally for solving small issues (think using = rather than > in a query) not a complete project.

Have you attempted writing this code yourself, if so what errors is it spitting out? rather than saying it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe external images are causing problem. So if there is any other way to upload external images to facebook feed then kindly tell me. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If the images are stored somewhere out there, you need to download them to your server and upload them to FB. You can't just tell FB an URL of an image, it's not working like this.

In order to upload fotos, you may use the "photo post" Method on the FB API. And it wants the binary data of the image. You may link an input and an output stream to that (what I would prefer using Java since no storage is needed).

Since your code is working with locally hosted images, just encapsulate that part and make the external image an internal one first.

Comment: Any smart method can you suggest for getting pictures on my server.

Comment: $tmpimg = tempnam ("/tmp", "fb_"); file_puts_content( $tmpimg, file_gets_content("imageurl") );